# BoxSeries3D cursor and mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I'm trying to have the data for the box under the mouse appear on hover like the 2D charts. There do not seem to be any interactive examples that I could find showing this and figuring it out from the API is eluding me. I'd also like to get the box that is clicked on by the mouse but the onMouseClick event added to the box series 3D that I tried as a starting point does not seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately `BoxSeries3D` or 3D series in general do not support any user interactions at the time. The same event methods as for 2D exist, but they don't do anything.

The development of new or missing LCJS features is adjusted in real time according to existing user needs, so it is a good thing that you asked this. If you are a licensed user, or would be interested in getting closer to the development to voice your requirements, please [contact us](https://www.arction.com/contact/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is a show stopper for me. Is there a way using the current API to figure this out? Seems like you could use the camera location, get xy coordinate and mouse events from document and extrapolate the relative 3D position. Of course I've no idea how one would do this in code.

Comment: Might be very hard from application side since you don't know the exact properties of the perspective. Theoretically possible, I guess.

Comment: But not practically possible with the current API?

Comment: Definitely not practically possible, yes.